# SolrCore initialization failures

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, solr

When I visit the dashboard it tells me:

> SolrCore initialization failures

The only warning line in  `/var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out` is:

```
WARNING: New index directory detected: old=null new=/var/solr/data/index/
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I got to this stage after hunting down errors in the log and fixing them, and at the point I asked, there were no more errors in the log, but I did see this in the HTTP console.

It turns out there wasn't a problem after all. If you view the console with the command-line browser `links` it will show this, not entirely correctly!

So, if you see this error in the console after you have fixed errors in the logs, just try interacting with the API (or visit it in a 'real' browser) it may already be working.